# group php array by subarray value

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I want to group an array by a subarray's value. If I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 591407753
            [propertyA] => 'text1'
            [propertyB] => 205
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 989201004
            [propertyA] =>'text2'
            [propertyB] => 1407
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 989201004
            [propertyA] => 'text3'
            [propertyB] => 1407
        )
)
```

I want to sort to group this array by a subarray's value so I can have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>Array
         (
          [userID]=>59140775
          [properties]=>Array
                        (
                         [0]=>text1
                        )
          [propertyB]=>205
         )
    [1]=>Array
        (
         [userID]=>989201004
         [properties]=>Array
                          (
                           [0]=>'text2'
                           [1]=>'text3'
                          )
         [propertyB]=>1047
        )   
)
```

How can I make this?

Before I had tried this:

```
   $result = array();
        foreach ($userArray as $record)
        {
            $id=$record['userID'];
            if(isset($result[$id]))
            {
                $result[$id]['propertyA'][]=array($record['propertyA']);
            }
            else {
                  $record["propertyA"]=array($record['propertyA']);
                  unset($record['tweet']);
                  $result[$id]=$record;
                }
        }
```

the problem was for the `propertyA`. I was an the result an additional property `propertyA` with the table like this:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>Array (
        [userID]=>989201004
        [propertyA]=>'text2'
        [properties]=>Array(
            [0]=>'text2'
            [1]=>'text3'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the job. I hope it is self-explanatory:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $record) {
    if (!isset($result[$record['userID']])) {
        $result[$record['userID']] = array(
            'userID' => $record['userID'],
            'properties' => array($record['propertyA']),
            'propertyB' => $record['propertyB'],
        );
    }
    else {
        $result[$record['userID']]['properties'][] = $record['propertyA'];
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: dont do the work for him/her. Let them show you what they have tried first. Push them to learn, not to use you.

Comment: I got your point. Lets call this teaching by example this time :)

Comment: before i had tried this: foreach ($userArray as $record)
        {
            $id=$record['userID'];
            if(isset($result[$id]))
            {
                $result[$id]['tweets'][]=array($record['tweet']);
            }
            else {
                  $record["tweets"]=array($record['tweet']);
                 // unset($record['tweet']);
                  $result[$id]=$record;
                }
        }   . But i had a result with an additional propertyA

Comment: ok, thanks, i edited my question above, and i wrote one of the tries that i had made and was near the result just for learning scopes